# Spring Data JPA and Sql Server: %like% behavior is different from JPQL spec

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I use following method:

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM UserEntity u WHERE LOWER(u.loginName) LIKE ?1")
Iterable<UserEntity> findAllUsersByNameLike(String likePattern);
```

and pass "%[08" as a parameter.

In result I have different responses from Sql Server and from Oracle database.

Oracle behaves as expected and treat `[` as an ordinary symbol and returns user entities that end with `[08`.

However, Sql Server treat `[` as a special T-SQL symbol (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql) and returns user entities with login names that end with `0` or `8`.

That is not correct according to JPQL spec (http://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_04/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_like)  that states that `all other characters [except % and _] stand for themselves`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you set the correct dialect?

Comment: @LipingHuang Yes, SQLServer2008Dialect

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `ESCAPE` keyword. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql):

> *escape_character*: Is a character that is put in front of a wildcard character to indicate that the wildcard should be interpreted as a regular character and not as a wildcard. *escape_character* is a character expression that has no default and must evaluate to only one character.

For example:

```
SELECT u 
FROM UserEntity u 
WHERE LOWER(u.loginName) LIKE '%![08' ESCAPE '!'`
```

Comment: No. Escape needs to be used only for `%` and `_` symbols.

Comment: No, it will also escape `[`,  `]` and `^` characters

Comment: I can't, because @Query will fail in Oracle with ORA-01424 error (only % or _ is allowed after escape character).

Comment: Then you need to have different queries for SQL vs Oracle.